# Javascript dynamic rows column

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I have a table of content which I want to rearrange its row and column based on user's window size using `window.onresize`.

```
window.onresize = function () {

    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var nocolumn = Math.floor(w / 252);
    if (nocolumn == 0) {
        nocolumn = 1;
    }

    var table = document.getElementById("MainContent_DataList1");
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var link = tbody.getElementsByTagName("a");

    var norow = Math.ceil(link.length / nocolumn);
    tbody.innerHTML = "";

    console.log(norow + " " + link.length + " " + nocolumn);
    for (var i = 0; i < norow; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        tbody.appendChild(row);
        for (var j = 0; j < nocolumn; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            row.appendChild(cell);
            if ((i * nocolumn + j) < link.length) {
                cell.appendChild(link[i * nocolumn + j]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I dont understand why the variable "link" array becomes empty after I use `innerHTML = "";` but I stored it before its cleared. Is it somewhere I did wrongly or there are other ways to do this?

Comment: Can you post the full page or link to jsfiddler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete the innerHTML you delete the DOM objects thus every reference to them will point to null.

A work around it will be to clone these objects:

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = {};
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}

window.onresize = function () {

    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var nocolumn = Math.floor(w / 252);
    if (nocolumn == 0) {
        nocolumn = 1;
    }

    var table = document.getElementById("MainContent_DataList1");
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var tmp = tbody.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var link = clone(tmp);

    var norow = Math.ceil(link.length / nocolumn);
    tbody.innerHTML = "";

    ...
}
```

Credit for the `clone()` method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/1057429

Comment: Far simpler (and safer) to iterate over the NodeList by index and assign to an array (i.e. convert the NodeList to an array).

Comment: `When you delete the innerHTML you delete the DOM objects thus every reference to them will point to null.` is incorrect. They are removed from the NodeList created by `getElementsByTagName`, other references not involving a live NodeList are unaffected (such as assigning references from an array or using [querySelectorAll](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall), which creates static NodeLists).

Comment: @RobG maybe I'm missing something but if you'll try to debug his code, when you'll get to `tbody.innerHTML = "";` you can inspect the value of `link` and see that it becomes `null`

Comment: @RobG and about your first comment - I totally agree with you, for this specific case it'll be enough to convert the NodeList to an array, but I was aiming to provide a solution that will be more generic and can be in other cases of DOM elements as "an input" as well.

Comment: wow thanks all the quick answers! i didn't know i could clone these objects. i got it working already!

Comment: @alfasin—the important bit is "every reference". Only those that are formed by live NodeLists will be "null" (actually they'll be undefined, but whatever). Other references from say *getElementById* or after conversion to an array are fine.

Comment: Also "cloning" host objects as in the answer is not very robust. The result of the typeof operator is only specified for native objects, not for host ubjects which can return any value, or even throw an error. Nor are the properties necessarily enumerable, and you may bet more properties than you expect. Far better to iterate over the object using specified behaviour to create an equivalent array.

Comment: @RobG I'm still not sure I understand (please bear with me): if you copy the values in the NodeList to an array - of course the values will be there, but if you'll try to get the values from that NodeList again after assigning `tbody.innerHTML = "";` using `getElementById` it won't work.

Comment: @alfasin—the NodeList returned by *getElementsByTagName* is live, so any change to the DOM also updates the NodeList, as if you called *getElementsByTagName* again. There are many such lists or collections, e.g. table.rows, select.options, document.images, document.links, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have suggested, *getElementsByTagName* returns a **live** NodeList. Therefore, when you delete all the elements from the body, the NodeList is updated to contain no nodes.

As an alternative, you can use *querySelectorAll*, which returns a static NodeList, or use *getElementsByTagName* and assign references to an array before clearing the nodes from the body, e.g.

```
function getNodes() {
  var tbody = document.body || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var nodes, link;

  if (tbody.querySelectorAll) {
    link = tbody.querySelectorAll('*');
  } else {
    nodes = tbody.getElementsByTagName("*");
    link = [];

    for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      link[i] = nodes[i];
    }
  }
  return link;
}
```